# Passing height of a div from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

What is the best way to pass non-form data from a view to a controller in CodeIgniter?  I am trying to pass the height of a div in a view to its controller.  For example, I would like to pass the variable below:

`var myDivHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;`

Thanks!

Comment: You should use ajax to pass div height.

Comment: Controllers do their work before view do. Firstly, router handle your request and point controller, after that controller do his work and after that view start do his work (output data etc). Why you need height of your div in controller? If you need to change height of your div or smth like that you have to use javascript/jquery tools for it.